# Custom object two-way databinding android:text

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I've created myself some simple class for validating fields through two-way databinding.

```
public class ValidatedField extends BaseObservable{
            private String mValue;

            @Bindable
            public String getValue()
            {
                return mValue;
            }


            public void setValue(String value)
            {
                if(Objects.equals(value, mValue)) return;

                mValue = value;
                notifyPropertyChanged(BR.value);
            }
    ...
}
```

In ViewModel I setup this class and bind it to view as usual in databinding
(all binding actually works so no error here).

```
public ValidatedField phoneNumber = new ValidatedField();
```

In layout, I have view with android:text property and I setup:

```
<EditText
   android:text="@={viewModel.phoneNumber.value}" 
/>
```

And everything works like a charm.

And my question is: **is it possible to skip '.value' from layout** so that it looks like this:

```
<EditText
   android:text="@={viewModel.phoneNumber}" 
/>
```

I could make it work if it was one way binding e.g. through binding conversion like this:

```
@BindingConversion
public static String convertValidatedFieldToString(ValidatedField field){
    return field.getValue();
}
```

But I'm not able to set new value to existing ValidatedField.
I've tried to use @InverseBindingAdapter but that's without luck because it would create every time new object and not just updated value of existing one.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static ValidatedField convertStringToValidatedField(TextView view)
{
    return new ValidatedField(view.getText().toString());
}
```

Thank you!

---

**Edit:** 
I should've said that I have other @Bindable fields in the class. e.g:

```
@Bindable
public boolean getIsError()
{
    return mIsError;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could've just extend `ObservableField<String>` and then override its `set` method.
so like:

```
public class ValidatedField extends ObservableField<String> {
    @Override
    public void set(String value) {
        if (get().equals(value))
            return;
        super.set(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work but only if there are no other Bindable fields in the class. If I wanted to check for example phoneNumber.isError  for accessor Bindable public boolean getIsError() { return mIsError; } it says that Error: Could not find accessor java.lang.String.error

Answer (score 0):

Databindings is lacking an `InverseBindingConversion`. At the moment it's not working like you intent to use it.

So you have to write `@={viewModel.phoneNumber.value}` anytime.